# 'Searching' through JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json, search, compare

Here I show an example of what I am currently using, it is working but not efficiently enough. I have been stumped for a couple of days now on trying to find an effective alternative but I lack the knowledge.

I have 2 JSON files, both share the same keys but the values change.

```
$file_data = file_get_contents('./data_1.json');
$json_data_1 = json_decode($file_data, true);
$file_data = file_get_contents('./data_2.json');
$json_data_2 = json_decode($file_data, true);

foreach($json_data_1["items"] as $key_1=>$val_1){
 foreach($json_data_2["items"] as $key_2=>$val_2){
  if ($val_1['guy'] == $val_2['guy']) {

        echo "Match Found!";
        // here I check for any differences
        // in other values
        break(1);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what are you trying to achieve? Just looking for the first shared value?

Comment: Yes, there is a value under 'Guy' that will be the same in both JSON files that I am trying to find a match. The above works, just not effectively.

Comment: see my answer, let me know if you get lost and will edit accordingly ;)

Comment: gonna give them both a shot! will share my results. Thanks guys!

Comment: Thanks guys, really appreciate the help. But I have a problem with both methods, they both work but not as I need them too. Now they both work but only if both the JSON files are in the same order, but mine change slightly and sometimes contains new entries but in the same format as the others.

Answer (score 1):

```
$file_data = file_get_contents('./data_1.json');
$json_data_1 = json_decode($file_data, true);
$file_data = file_get_contents('./data_2.json');
$json_data_2 = json_decode($file_data, true);

 print_r(array_diff($json_data_1["items"],$json_data_2["items"]);
```

https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: Thanks Robert, I couldn't get this to give me any results but this would also have the same problem as below if the data was in a different order, (format stays the same)

Answer (score 0):

since it users the thae same key's you only need to use one foreach loop and use the key.

try this code:

```
$file_data = file_get_contents('./data_1.json');
$json_data_1 = json_decode($file_data, true);
$file_data = file_get_contents('./data_2.json');
$json_data_2 = json_decode($file_data, true);

foreach($json_data_1["items"] as $key_1=>$val_1){
  if ($val_1['guy'] == $json_data_2['items'][$key_1]['guy']) {

        echo "Match Found!";
        // here I check for any differences
        // in other values
        break(1);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So this looks great, and would work perfectly but my data_2.json doesn't have the entries in the same order every time. How can I go about this?

Comment: If it users name keys and not number keys it should still work.